# slideToggle equivlanet for when a page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to hide some content in collapsible panels, to do this I am using the following mark up and script:

HTML

```
<div class="trigger">Collapsible Header 1 - Click to toggle</div>
<div class="panel">
    content 1
</div>

<div class="trigger">Collapsible Header 2 - Click to toggle</div>
<div class="panel">
    content 2
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("medium");
    });
});
```

A fiddle of it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LkTf8/1/

This works great, however I am trying to start with the panels collapsed. Currently, they are open, not closed. What is the best approach to start with the panels collapsed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `.panel` to `display: none`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LkTf8/164/)

Comment: @user3010406 no problem. Just be sure to approve this answer as resolved when you can.